# Where is my google places API key?

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

Spent such a long time looking for it in Google's console page but seriously cannot find it.

Where is it??

I'm trying to figure this library out and it says

**P.S Common mistake: DON NOT USE Google Maps API v3 key, you need Places API KEY instead, otherwise all requests will just fail with REQUEST_DENIED status code**

https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/ios/start#step-5-get-an-api-key
You can check in this link, there's a complete walktrough to get an API key.

Answer (score 0):

See the "Authentication" section on this page for instructions on obtaining an API Key.

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro

(I'm providing a link rather than pasting into the answer as the linked documentation will update if the process ever changes)